# Attach content database after wss 3.0 reinstall

Tags: wss-3.0

I tried to install sp3 for wss 3.0 SharePoint crashed. So after following directions on uninstalling and reinstalling things aren't quite right.

I created a new application and content db, then deleted that db using stsadm and attached the old content db to the new Web application.

The question is where are all the libraries, documents and subsides.

I have a blank site that says it is connected to the content db but no content.

What did I do wrong?

I can create the sub sites and connect the appropriate TFS project to it,  and work items show. But still no documents or none of the customization that I had.